# 3600MHz memory doesn't work to the spec

Tags: memory, amd-radeon, amd-ryzen, ddr

I'm trying to configure AMD R9 Radeon branded memory kit (model R9S432G3606U2K) to work at it's specified frequency, which is 3600. The motherboard is Asus Prime B550-Plus and, according to it's specs, this frequency is well within its capabilities. The bios is updated to the latest, the CPU is 5600X (no OC applied).

Though it seems the only thing I need is to activate XMP/D.O.C.P profile in the bios settings. Then it sets the memory clock target at 3600 (@1.35V), infinity fabric target at 1800, timings all according to SPD. Seems legit and should probably work, but then the system just doesn't start up.

What's weird is that the memory doesn't even have proper SDP modes above 2400MHz. Basically it's either 2400 or 3600. So is there something I've missed (I'm not an overclocking and/or hardware expert), or it's just a bad kit or a bad match between the kit and the motherboard and there is nothing to do about it?

Comment: What's really weird, is that the kit number when searched for, only seems to bring up Russian & Ukrainian web sites. I think you need to check the chip id markings and see what they say.

Comment: Are you mixing ram sticks of different speeds on the same board? If yes, then it's worth noting that most PC's will default all the memory speed to match the slowest stick installed.

Comment: Turns out that just installing the modules into the other slots pair solves the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after some research, it appeared to me that some slots on the motherboard are more equal than others. Reinstalling the RAM modules into the slots A2/B2 solved all the problems and the RAM just worked with the D.O.C.P. profile right away.